# Removal of special characters in a txt file using spark

Tags: regex, scala, dataframe, apache-spark

I have a txt file which comprises of data like

```
3,3e,4,5   
3,5s,4#,5   
5,6,2,4  
and so on
```

now what I have to do is to remove these characters and using spark and then add all the values into an aggregated sum.

How to get remove the special characters and sum all the values.

I have created a dataframe and used regexp_replace to remove the special characters.

But by using `.withColumn` clause I can only remove the special characters one by one and not as a whole which I believe is not optimized code.

Secondly, I have to add all the values into an aggregated sum. How to get the aggregate value.

Comment: do you have fix four column in you data set? if not then how you are creating DataFrame

Answer (score 0):

If you have fixed number of column in input data then you can use below approach.

```
//Input Text file 
scala> val rdd = sc.textFile("/spath/stack.txt")

scala> rdd.collect()
res108: Array[String] = Array("3,3e,4,5   ", "3,5s,4#,5   ", 5,6,2,4)

//remove special characters
scala> val rdd1 = rdd.map{x => x.replaceAll("[^,0-9]", "")}

scala> rdd1.collect
res109: Array[String] = Array(3,3,4,5, 3,5,4,5, 5,6,2,4)

//Conver RDD into DataFrame
scala> val df  = rdd1.map(_.split(",")).map(x => (x(0).toInt,x(1).toInt,x(2).toInt,x(3).toInt)).toDF

scala> df.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+
|_1 |_2 |_3 |_4 |
+---+---+---+---+
|3  |3  |4  |5  |
|3  |5  |4  |5  |
|5  |6  |2  |4  |
+---+---+---+---+

//local UDF to sum up value    
scala> val sumUDF = udf((r:Row) => {
     | r.getAs("_1").toString.toInt + r.getAs("_2").toString.toInt + r.getAs("_3").toString.toInt + r.getAs("_4").toString.toInt
     | })


//Expected DataFrame
scala> val finaldf = df.withColumn("sumcol", sumUDF(struct(rdd2.columns map col: _*)))

scala> finaldf.show(false)
+---+---+---+---+------+
|_1 |_2 |_3 |_4 |sumcol|
+---+---+---+---+------+
|3  |3  |4  |5  |15    |
|3  |5  |4  |5  |17    |
|5  |6  |2  |4  |17    |
+---+---+---+---+------+
```